# Android java compare xml string with edittext

Tags: android, xml, string, if-statement, compare

I want to compare a xml string with a string from an edittext oder button.
first I set the text of the button:

```
button1.setText(getString(R.string.okey));
```

and now I want to check if the text from the button is the same as R.string.okey from the xml file. Like this I can leave out a new variable.

Is it possible to check if the strings are the same with something like this?

```
if (button1.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.okey))){
}
```

But that doesn't work for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your error ? Post your error.. Your code is proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this must work, its just to simple. you must change somehow text on button or maybe `getString` returns different text (`Locale` changed?). use logging or debugger to check what is `button1.getText().toString()` and `getString(R.string.okey)` at the moment of comparison (`equals` call)

```
boolean areEqual = button1.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.okey));

Log.i("justChecking", "getString:" + getString(R.string.okey) + 
    ", button1.getText:" + button1.getText().toString() +
    ", are equal:" + areEqual);

if (areEqual){
}
```

How to [Write and View Logs with Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Comment: I also don't uderstand what do you mean... `button1.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.okey))` will work (`true`) when texts are the same... you have wrote "But that doesn't work for me" - so texts are different. log both `String`s in Logcat and compare by yourself (added `Log` line to answer)

Comment: I have a xml string file for english and german. But now I tried it, and it worked. I don't konw why it didn't work before. but Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Store them in variables

```
String a = button1.getText()+"";
String b = getString(R.string.str)+"";
if(a.equals(b)){  }
```

Comment: yes, but then I used a new variable again, and I wanted to avoid that.